# What does the normalization factor mean in Bayesian learning?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, marginal-distribution

Suppose we want to learn the distribution of a random variable $x$.

Assuming it's from a Gaussian distribution: $x\sim\mathcal{N}(\theta,1)$ with constant variance 1, we can learn the parameter $\theta$ from some data by using Bayesian learning. The prior distribution of $\theta$ is set to be a Gaussian $$p(\theta) = \mathcal{N}(\theta;0,1)$$ The likelihood of an observed data point would then be $$p(x|\theta) = \mathcal{N}(x;\theta,1)$$ The posterior distribution is obtained by multiplying the prior and the likelihood and normalizing: $$p(\theta|x)=\frac{p(\theta)p(x|\theta)}{\int p(\theta)p(x|\theta) d\theta}=\frac{p(\theta)p(x|\theta)}{p(x)}$$

What does the normalization factor $p(x)$ mean in the above posterior distribution equation?

It's denoted as "$p(x)$" but can't be the true distribution of $x$ as the prior and likelihood function are completely hypothetical, meaning the whole joint distribution $p(x,\theta)$ is hypothetical as well. So how do we interpret $p(x)$?

Disregarding this unexplainable "$p(x)$", the remaining learning process makes good sense to me. As we observe more and more instances of $x\in\mathcal{D}$ from its true distribution, the posterior mean deviates from the prior mean and approaches the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta=\mathop{\arg\min}_\theta p(\mathcal{D}|\theta)$. Imagine the true distribution $p(x)=\delta(x-1)$, i.e. $x$ always equals to 1. the posterior mean should approach to 1 in the limit of infinite observations instead of approaching prior mean of 0.

All is well until I came across a disturbing description on p.74 in "Bishop C M. Pattern recognition and machine learning[M]. springer, 2006.", which states:

> Consider a general Bayesian inference problem for a parameter $\theta$ for which we have observed a data set $\mathcal{D}$. The following result
> $$\mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta]=\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{D}[\mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta|\mathcal{D}]]$$
> where
> $$\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{D}[\mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta|\mathcal{D}]]=\int \Big\{ \int \theta p(\theta|\mathcal{D})d\theta\Big\}p(\mathcal{D})d\mathcal{D}$$
> $$\mathbb{E}_\theta[\theta]=\int \theta p(\theta)d\theta$$
> says that the posterior mean of $\theta$, averaged over the distribution generating the data, is equal to the prior mean of $\theta$.

I can see this equation is correct, but how does this tell us anything about Bayesian learning? The author clearly indicates $p(\mathcal{D})$ is the real distribution which we want to learn, however, going through the constructed example above, I found it is not the case. What am I missing here?

Comment: This seem like two different questions to me (first about the normalizing constant, and second about the passage in the PRML book). To keep things focused, could you remove the second part and repost it as a separate question? Or, if they're connected, perhaps you could edit to clarify how.